# Definition of area

Tags: geometry

I find the question of "What is the area of a circle of radius $5$?" misleading. The answer is $25 \pi$, but what the question really should be saying is "What is the area contained inside a circle of radius $5$?" Otherwise it seems like it is asking for the area of a line segment. Since the definition of a circle is just a continuous line segment, saying it that way makes it seem like the answer is $0$.

Comment: You are right, but it is understood.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're interpreting the text literally. Let's decompose the sentence.

"What is the area of a circle of radius $5$" is the question. We can take "of" to mean "belonging to" without adding or losing information. Thus, the question becomes "What is the area belonging to a circle of radius $5$". To talk about the area that a circle owns is the same thing as the area that belongs to it. Thus, it is roughly equivalent to your albeit less ambigious statement formed. (It really doesn't make *sense* to talk about the area of a line—one would usually use more precise terms, or not talk about it in the first place.)

While I do take some leaps in meaning, this is the way the sentence is meant to be interpreted. Usually geometry textbook-writers don't anticipate such an analytical decomposition of their questions ;)